# How to replace a legend with a colorbar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, line, matlab-figure, colorbar

I have a line plot with several lines but rather than a legend, I would prefer to have a colorbar to indicate the value (of time in my case) for each line.

My best attempt so far is as follows (I am only including the relevant parts of the code):

```
colormap('jet');
cmin = min(t);
cmax = max(t);
cmp1 = jet(7); % say, there are 7 lines in my plot 
colororder(cmp1); 

plot() % plot without including 'Color' argument 

colorbar('Location', 'eastoutside');
clim([cmin cmax]);
```

The issue I am facing here is that the colors of the lines do not exactly correspond to the colorbar.

See [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MiG0.jpg) for an example. You can see clearly that the colors do not exactly match the values in the colorbar (the legend has the correct values). For e.g., if you check the 3600 line, it is the max value of the colorbar which corresponds to a deep red color; however in the plot it is a bright red.

Comment: Did you try `colormap(cmp1);`?

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
colormap('jet');
t = [1, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3000, 3600];
cmin = min(t);
cmax = max(t);
cmp1 = jet(7); % say, there are 7 lines in my plot 
colororder(cmp1); 

plot(magic(7), 'linewidth', 3) % plot without including 'Color' argument 

cbar = colorbar('Location', 'eastoutside');
clim([cmin, cmax])
set(cbar, 'Ticks', t)
```

[image]

See if the second one works for you. I do not get your intention fully.

```
colormap('jet');
t = [1, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3000, 3600];
cmin = min(t);
cmax = max(t);
cmp1 = jet(7); % say, there are 7 lines in my plot 
colororder(cmp1); 

plot(magic(7), 'linewidth', 3) % plot without including 'Color' argument 

cbar = colorbar('Location', 'eastoutside');
colormap(cmp1)
temp = movmean(linspace(0, 1, 7 + 1), 2);
set(cbar, 'Ticks', temp(2:end))
set(cbar, 'TickLabels', {'foo','bar','ha','ho','hi','hu'})
```

[image]

Comment: See if second one works. I do not actually understand your intention fully.

Comment: @JulieJ. Please provide in your question a code snippet that can be run and that exactly reproduces your problem. Otherwise people trying to help may waste their time solving a problem which is not the one you have, as seems to be the case here